# Sharepoint 2010 Trial ended error after upgrade to licenced product

Tags: 2010

I have a sharepoint 2010 installation that I have been using on a trail version while my boss orgnised a movl subscribtion which would include sharepoint. Thats done now and last week the activation key was put into sharepoint. This did work as i could not install office web apps until the server was a full licecned prouduct.

Now today all the sites that i created during the trial period are erroring and telling me ....

The trial period for this product has expired.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: db3adbce-1c76-44e0-bd10-883868241106

Date and Time: 8/13/2011 10:48:46 AM

....

Help Please I dont want to have to rebuild everything again :(

Thanks for any advice

Dave

Comment: DO NOT UNINSTALL OFFICE WEB APPS on sharepoint2010 ,It takes the whole freaking sharepoint 2010 and iis with it .... BALLS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you run the SharePoint config utility on each wfe & app server in your farm to see if that cleans it up.  You can run it from:

Start > All Programs > Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products > SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration

- or -

from the command-line:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093.aspx

NOTE: **psconfig.exe** can be found in `Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\bin` on the drive where you installed SharePoint.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for the reply, i just had a small hickup and unistalled my sharepoint while uninstalling the office web apps ( which i was recomemded to do on a different forum.... i now have found this and know its a BIG mistake not reading prompt boxes fully.... http://vinaybhatia.blogspot.com/2011/06/never-never-everuninstall-office-web.html    ill mark you answer as answered and will bookmark your link incase i get it on the rebuild. Thanks

Comment: ROb I believe your post was in answer to my delete sharepoint comment, i thought orginall it was for the main topic. I just ran the sharepoint products configuration wizard and its all back up and working!! Thank you for the pointer!! Saved me hours of hassel and work!

Comment: This fixed the trial error ...http://retrohack.com/sharepoint-2010-trial-period-expired/